# How to make an ImageView popup on click

Tags: android

I want to be able to click on an ImageView in a list and have it popup on click, like in the Tumblr and Path app.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

PS: I've tired using a dialog already.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know its old question. but ill add this for future reference. 
You can use this library to show image as a Popup. https://github.com/chathuralakmal/AndroidImagePopup

```
final ImagePopup imagePopup = new ImagePopup(this);

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /** Initiate Popup view **/
            imagePopup.initiatePopup(imageView.getDrawable());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a component called [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html), you can find some example of usage here:
http://android-er.blogspot.com.br/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html

It is slightly similar to a Dialog, but you have more control over it.